# Integral closedness of ideals preserved under isomorphism?

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra

Let $R$ be a Noetherian ring. Let $0\neq I,J\subseteq R$ be ideals both containing a non zero divisor, such that $I\simeq J$. If $I$ is an integrally closed ideal, is $J$ integrally closed ? Thank you.

I see that it is true if $R$ is an integrally closed domain : The isomorphism $I\simeq J$ is given by multiplication by an element $\alpha/\beta\in Frac(R)$. So multiplying any integral equation (of ideals) of degree $n$ over $J$ by $(\alpha/\beta)^n$ gives an integral equation over $I$.

Comment: I think it is true that $Hom_R(I,J) \subset K(R)$, where $K(R) = \{ a/b : a,b \in R, b~ndz \}$ is the total ring of fractions. In other words, such an isomorphism is multiplication by an element of $K(R)$ and hence it is of the form $a/b$.

Comment: Thanks, I see that then it is true for any integrally closed ring. But I don't see how to get rid of the $R$ integrally closed assumption.

Comment: Where did you use that assumption (integrally closed) in your 2nd paragraph?

Comment: Suppose $a^n+j_1a^{n-1}+\dots+j_n=0$ is an integral equation for $a\in R$ over $J$. Let $q:=a\cdot \alpha/\beta\in Q(R)$. Multiplying the above equation by $(\alpha/\beta)^n$ gives an integral equation for $q$ over $R$, but $R$ is integrally closed, so $q\in R$. But the equation is also then an integral equation for $q$ over $I$, so $q\in I$ and hence $a\in J$ ($\alpha$ is also an nzd since $I$ contains a nzd).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I think the ideals $xA$ and $yA$, where $A = k[x,y]/(x^2-y^3)$ provide an example. In $A$, $x$ is in the integral closure of $yA$, but not vice versa.

Comment: Thanks. is $xA$ integrally closed in your example?

Comment: I guess so (though I have not checked it, rigorously). Also, you can use $1A$ for $xA$ instead and $1A$ is integrally closed. You may think of the semi-group counterpart $k[t^2, t^3] \subset k[t]$. Here $x,y$ correspond to $t^3,t^2$ respectively.

Comment: Sorry about the previous commnet, $xA$ is not integrally closed as $y^2$ is integral over $xA$. One should use $1A$ or there is a good chance that high powers of $x$ or $y$ will do the job.

Comment: Thanks, I see. Certainly not true in general then. Very unlikely even if we take proper ideals right?